# linux не работает dns с ipv6, в чем проблема?

Tags: linux, сеть, debian, dns, ipv6

У меня debiab 9, на хосте есть ipv4 и ipv6.
Я хотел бы полностью отключить ipv4 и чтобы по дефолту использовался ipv6.

Из файла /etc/network/interfaces я удалил ipv4 и оставил только ipv6. Пока что все работает, я могу подключиться к хосту по ipv6, а по ipv4 уже не могу, как я и хотел.

Но возникла проблема с DNS, если я напишу, например ping google.com, то будет ошибка:

```
 ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

И так везде ошибки запросов dns, например при apt update, curl и т.п.

В конфиге /etc/resolv.conf есть DNS сервера ipv6:

```
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage
# nameserver config
nameserver 213.133.98.98
nameserver 213.133.99.99
nameserver 213.133.100.100
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:9999
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:1010
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:9898
```

Я еще думал, что проблема в hostname, он у меня остался ipv4. Я сделал ipv6 aaaa запись в домене, указал в hostname и это не помогло.

Как же тогда исправить?

Comment: С пингом при ipv6 надо указывать интерфейс. Попробуйте так : `ping -6 -I enp3s0 google.com`

Comment: убедитесь dig, что указанные ipv6 dns отвечают. попробуйте удалить ip4 dns из resolv.conf

Comment: для использования [icmpv6](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMPv6) нужно явно указать опцию `-6` для программы *ping*, либо использовать симлинк *ping6*, если мэйтэйнеры вашего дистрибутива позаботились о его наличии. два несвязанных вопроса (про ping и про apt) в одном вопросе задавать не следует. используйте кнопку «задать вопрос» для каждого отдельного вопроса.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin спасибо за ответ. просто apt и ping не работают из-за общей проблемы - dns. как все остальные команды, через которые делаются соединения какие либо. просто это как-то неудобно для каждой команды искать альтернативу для ipv6, хотелось задать поведение ipv6 по умолчанию